# Proving $\sin^2 (\pi x) - \frac{1}{x}$ is not eventually positive

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$f:\mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is eventually positive if
$$
\exists M\in\mathbb{R}^+ \ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^+ \ \ (x \geq M) \rightarrow (f(x)>0)
$$
Prove that $f(x) = \sin ^2 (\pi x) - \frac{1}{x}$ is not eventually positive.

I found the negation to be
$$\forall M >0 \ \exists x >0 \ \ (x\geq M)\wedge (f(x)\leq 0) $$

I always have trouble doing these type of questions.
Can someone give advice or some intuition in thinking about what choice to make?
In particular, I'm unsure of where to start. In limit proofs I think usually we'd start at the end, so I'd start with 
$$f(x) = \sin^2 (\pi x) - \frac{1}{x} \leq 0
$$
which seems to be true for "small" enough $x$ values (by sketching the two graphs up) but not sure what to do now.

Comment: You need to look at **large** $x$, not small $x$. How can you choose $x$ to guarantee $\sin^2\pi x$ is small?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that it is, then for some $M>0$, $\sin^{2}(\pi x)-1/x>0$ for all $x\geq M$. Choose some integer $N\geq M$, then $\sin^{2}(\pi N)-1/N=-1/N<0$.

Comment: So I should pick $N := 2\times \lceil{M}\rceil$? since that quantity is greater than $M$?

Comment: Yes you can do that, but the fact is, positive integers are unbounded, such a candidate always exists.